# C после выхода из функции пропадают указатели

Tags: c++

Кусок кода для Arduino (отлаживался в Visual studio) для выделения параметров из текстовой строки.
На вход подается строка "45 5 6" и надо ее разобрать и положить в массив поэлементно.
На выходе надо получить:

```
tokens1[0]="45";
tokens1[1]="5";
tokens1[2]="6";
```

Код совершенно простой.
На вход передается указатель на массив char *
Внутри делаю malloc и раскидываю строки.
Внутри функция полностью рабочая, но почему то на выходе все ранее заданные в функции указатели исчезают, т.е ";
tokens1[1] == NULL

Вопрос - куда деваются указатели с выделенной памятью на выходе из функции ?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

void parceArgumenst(char *str, char* (*tokens)[4]) {
    //   char str[] = "1546 44 55 ";
    char s[] = " ";
    char *token;
    char* tkncpy;

    //   char * tokens[4];

    /* get the first token */
    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) { *tokens[i] = NULL; }

    int j = 0;
    token = strtok(str, s);

    /* walk through other tokens */
    while (token != NULL) {

        tkncpy = (char *)malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
        strcpy(tkncpy, token);

        *tokens[j] = tkncpy;
        j++;

        token = strtok(NULL, s);
    }
}


int main()
{
    char* tokens1[4];
    char str[] = "45 5 6";
    parceArgumenst(str, &tokens1);

    std::cout << "Name: " << tokens1[1] << "\n";


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот эта строчка `*tokens[j] = tkncpy;` понимается компилятором как `*(tokens[j]) = tkncpy;`, и приводит к выходу за границы массива для `j != 0`.

Нужно добавить скобки: `(*tokens)[j] = tkncpy;`.

Comment: Мне кажеться что от strtok надо избавиться как можно скорее, это неоднозначная функция, она буфер хранит в себе, статиком, и неловким движением его можно испортить .. :) подойдёт на замену strsep или strtok_r в крайнем случае, а можно и свой написать, что иногда бывает более оптимально. :)

Comment: Лучше изменить декларацию в функции, например `char *tokens []) {` и далее `tokens[j] = tkncpy;`

Comment: @NewView: Почему это "лучше"? Указатель на весь массив передают тогда, когда хотят потребовать конкретного фиксированного размера массива. В данном случае - ровно 4. И это правильно. А ваш вариант допускает передачу любого массива, без проверки размера.

Comment: Это точно, любого размера, вряд-ли в реальной ситуации он будет фиксированным. И такие декларации, сложно воспринимаемые на глаз, на практике приводят к неприятным ошибкам, чему пример данный пост в том числе.